Get selection offsets in JS/HTML with formatting information
I am building a web interface for annotating texts.
The user should select a portion of the text (using the mouse) and write some side notes about it. When I save the annotation, I need to keep the offsets of the selected text. Note that the text is taken from a TXT file that may include spaces, tabulations, newlines, etc.
Now I put the text into a <pre> tag and call the Selection object in JS to get the offsets. By using a <pre> container, I have perfect correspondence between the offsets of the selection and the offsets in the TXT file.
Now I need to add some formatting information on this text (for instance, highlight the portions of text already annotated by other users): if I add some <span>s with the background color, I mess the information about the selection and the offsets.
Any idea on how to deal with this problem?


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
    const selection = window.getSelection()

    let selectedText = selection.toString()
    let startOffset = selection.anchorOffset
    let endOffset = selection.focusOffset
    
    console.log(selectedText, startOffset, endOffset)
  })
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="file-content">This is my text.

I can have spaces     and newlines.


Bye!</pre>

<button id="button">
Click me
</button>




you might need to keep track of the inserted <span>s then you can calculate back to the offsets?

Could you please share your relevant code?

@StefanHegny this is what I'd like to avoid because it's a mess, but it's the only solution I've imagined

@user27425627 This is an example of the code: jsfiddle.net/ziorufus/1q7c5e4g/4 (just select some text from  and click the button)

Post code as a [mcve].

@zer00ne this code contains an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ziorufus/1q7c5e4g/4

@AlessioPalmeroAprosio the reason why code is required on the site is because if the fiddle no longer exists your question is useless to future readers. Just click the brackets button <>

@zer00ne I added the code, sorry for non having done it before

@AlessioPalmeroAprosio so is the text originally on a txt file? Then that text is edited by the user how? How is all of the offset numbers used? Have you attempted to use <span>s yet? At any point do you use contenteditable?

This is an interesting problem, since the methods offered by window.getSelection API return selection offset from the innermost tag, we must find a hacky solution.
I suggest having 2 pre tags which the text contents are the same inside. first one is used only as a container which user can select the text from. and second will contain all the span tags used for styling and annotation and etc..
 <div style="width:300px; height:300px; position:relative">
            <!-- This pre tag is used only for keeping the text as plain portion of text -->
            <pre id="userSelection" style="position:absolute;margin:0;top:0;color:rgba(0,0,0,0);">
                lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Sint praesentium, ad repellat fuga consequuntur aut a laboriosam! Deserunt, fugiat aperiam, omnis esse vel, aliquid itaque in tempore sequi voluptatibus consequuntur.
            </pre>
            <!-- Using this tag you can style the elements-->
            <pre style="margin:0;z-index:0;user-select: none;">
                lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur <span style="color:red;">adipisicing</span> elit.Sint praesentium, ad repellat fuga consequuntur aut a laboriosam! Deserunt, fugiat aperiam, omnis esse vel, aliquid itaque in tempore sequi voluptatibus consequuntur.
            </pre>

            <button onclick="handleClick()">Click here</button>
        </div>

If you check the provided code above, second tag in this example contains the span for the word adipisicing, your JavaScript example will return adipisicing 56 67 which is the correct result.

Important note:

This is your responsibility to make both texts synced at all times.
This approach works great if you just want to highlight or change color of a selection. Since we rely on the fact that each character in both plain-text pre and styled pre are visually on the same position. this might not work great if you want to make a selection larger, bold, italic or etc...
The plaintext pre is invisible and the styled version has no user-select.
Finally, just know that with current API's provided by the browser you wont go far enough, If you are trying to get advanced functionalities in your app, you might as well use canvas or canvas based libraries for text processing (this is the approach used by
Google Docs).


It's a really interesting solution, and it seems to work well for my case!
